# Large Javascript Slowing Down Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm messing around with making my first Google Chrome Extension - A very simple one that basically replaces text on a specific page.

The problem is, the number of text that it searches & replaces is very large, so it's taking around 30-40 seconds to display each page.

So everything works OK, but I have this code:

> document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("Christian Bethancourt", "g"), "*Christian Bethancourt* - Canadians");
>
> document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("Kris Bryant", "g"), "*Kris Bryant* - Canadians");

But there are approximately 200 lines that it goes through to search. I tried minifying the script but it didn't do much.

Is there any better way to do this? Or a way to speed things up?

(For those wondering, it's for a Fantasy Baseball league that has full minors - so this would replace the prospects name with their name & team owner in yahoo's fantasy baseball pages)

Thanks!

Comment: Part of the issue is you are going through the entire page twice, or however many names your replacing names. Try moving the page to a variable and run every name you want through it. I would us a for(int i=0; i < page.length; i++) or something close and if/elseif/else or a case statement to do the regex.

Comment: It also can't help to be calling `document.body.innerHTML` 2n times.  Try just one call at the beginning and one at the end.